# How to filter data by many years

Tags: r

So I have a data that has many rows of country, year, and number of reported cases of cholera of that year. How should I go about filtering the data in ranges of years?

So I want data between 2008 - 2016 for example. For all I know, `filter(__)` seems only to do one year.

Also, how should I go about filtering for certain names in variables? So lets say I have a few rows that say X, Y, Z, C, D. How do I only filter for rows of "X" "Y" Z" for example?

Comment: `?between` and/or `filter` can take a complex expression (i.e. `>=` `<=`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give more context. It's not even clear what language you're talking about. Also, please add several tags that can help others find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`between()` and `%in%` are the operators you're looking for. To filter on both of your criteria simultaneously:

```
library(dplyr)
filtered_data <- (your_data %>%
     filter(between(year,2008,2016),
            interesting_row %in% c("X","Y","Z"))
)
```

Note that `between(year,2008,2016)` is (nearly) equivalent to `2008 <= year & year <= 2016`

Comment: Although the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates "thank you" comments; instead, if the answer solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark.